# For-loop and variables in PHP MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, for-loop

I have to select a lot of tables and Fields using PHP and MySQL. But the structure and naming of these are every time the same.

I have the tables **field_revision_blabla** and the fields **blablabla_value** from table-alias **blablabla_table**.

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($typeFields); $i++) {
    $query->join(
        "field_revision_".$typeFields[$i], 
        $typeFields[$i]."_table", 
        'n.nid = $typeFields[$i]."_table.entity_id"');
    $query->addField($typeFields[$i]."_table", $typeFields[$i]."_value");
}
```

But that gives me the error:

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[$i])."_table.entity_id" INNER JOIN field_revision_field_text field_text_table O' at line 2**

I think the error is in

```
'n.nid = $typeFields[$i]."_table.entity_id"'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO's color coding should have flagged this for you...along with the SQL statement complaining about variables in the query. Your `$typeFields[$i]` isn't being figured in the string.

```
"n.nid = " . $typeFields[$i] . "_table.entity_id"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of single, I doubt you have record in DB containing `n.nid = $typeFields[$i]."_table.entity_id"`:

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($typeFields); $i++) {
    $query->join(
        "field_revision_".$typeFields[$i], 
        $typeFields[$i]."_table", 
        "n.nid = ".$typeFields[$i]."_table.entity_id");
    $query->addField($typeFields[$i]."_table", $typeFields[$i]."_value");
}
```